# Twitter API get webhooks for my account [PHP]

Tags: api, twitter, notifications, webhooks

Do you know if it is possible to set up webhooks when there is activity on MY twitter account with API ?

For example :

- notification when I receive a like on my tweet
- notification when I receive a new subscriber on my account.

Etc ...

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, using the Account Activity API you can do this.

Comment: No... Account Activity API allows you to have the actions of people who are subscribed to the webhook. Account Activity API does not trigger webhook when I receive a like or when someone (who is not subscribed to the webhook) comments MY tweet, etc...

Comment: @andypiper Is it possible to talk together to have some help ? thanks you.

Comment: If you subscribe your own account to the Account Activity API webhook endpoint, then replies or likes on your Tweets will trigger an event.

Comment: I’m subscribed to my webhook with my account. I receive notifications when I like or when I reply but not when someone likes or replies my tweets. I don't need everyone to be logged into my webhook to receive their actions. I only need to have the actions that are done on MY profile via an average person (like, answer, quote, etc ...). But I'm afraid the API doesn't know how to do this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Once you have created a webhook, and subscribe to the webhook using your own account, you will receive the follow and reply events. Per the [Account Activity API documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/premium/account-activity-api/overview), I've highlighted the two relevant bullet points:

> You will receive all related activities below for each user subscription on your webhook registration:
>
> - Activity types Tweets (by user)
> - Tweet deletes (by user) @mentions (of
>   user)
> - Replies (to or from user)
> - Retweets (by user or of user)
> - Quote Tweets (by user or of user)
> - Retweets of Quoted Tweets (by user or of
>   user)
> - **Likes (by user or of user)**
> - **Follows (by user or of user)**
> - Unfollows (by user)
> - Blocks (by user)
> - Unblocks (by user)
> - Mutes (by user)
> - Unmutes (by user)
> - Direct Messages sent (by user)
> - Direct Messages received (by user)
> - Typing indicators (to user)
> - Read receipts (to user)
> - Subscription revokes (by user)

Note that you have to manually subscribe your own account to your own registered webhook using the API - this does not happen automatically. You also need to handle each received API event (the webhook will receive all types of event).

Comment: Hi Andy. I create my webhook, I'm subscribe to this webhook and i don't receive webhook when a other Twitter account like my Tweet... i'm receive webhook  when an other Twitter account follow my account... I receive webhook when I like a tweet, but I want to receive webhook when someone like MY tweets...

Comment: EDIT : It work !!! Thanks Andy !!!